# Can't boot after changing RAM?

Tags: boot, 18.04, startup, boot-repair

I tried to add another 4 gb RAM to my machine, but it failed to start so I decided to keep my already working RAM and removing the new one, but the same problem occurs. The problem which I am referring to is just prompting without any clue after Lenovo startup.

Someone suggested to test RAM using MemTest86. It simple ran 4 tests and all passed.

I've attached a screenshot for the state after starting my machine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by using the `boot-repair` tool. I found that I needed to add another partition 1M and flag it with a grub flag and `boot-repair` resolved the issue.